# Value generated from range have same pointer value

Tags: go

For these two struct

```
type A struct {
    Number *int
}

type B struct {
    Number int
}
```

If I want to loop on slice of B and assign the value of B.Number to new A.Number

```
func main() {
    aSlice := []A{}
    bSlice := []B{B{1}, B{2}, B{3}}
    for _, v := range bSlice {
        a := A{}
        a.Number = &v.Number
        aSlice = append(aSlice, a)
    }
}
```

I will found that all aSlice a.Number is the same value and same pointer.

```
for _, v := range aSlice {
        fmt.Printf("aSlice Value %v Pointer %v\n", *v.Number,v.Number)
    }
```

Will print
aSlice Value 3 Pointer 0x10414020
aSlice Value 3 Pointer 0x10414020
aSlice Value 3 Pointer 0x10414020

So does range only update the value of **_,v** in for loop and doesn't change the pointer ?

Full Code : https://play.golang.org/p/2wopH9HOjwj

Comment: Correct. `v` is the same variable in each iteration, only its value changes.

Comment: So go does this to save memory allocations?

Comment: Does what save memory allocations? Comparing the memory allocations of working code vs incorrect code seems irrelevant, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean that in every iteration in for loop `v.Number` will have the same pointer value but with different variable value .. so in every iteration go will update the pointer with new value ... instead of creating new pointer and assign new value to it.( So this save memory allocation)

Comment: If you're asking if that's why it works that way, I'm guessing it has more to do with simplicity than memory efficiency, but that's just a guess. If you really want to know you'd have to ask the Go creators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It occurred because variable `v` is created at the beginning of the loop and doesn't change. So,  every element in `aSlice` has a pointer to the same variable. You should write this:

```
for _, v := range bSlice {
    a := A{}
    v := v
    a.Number = &v.Number
    aSlice = append(aSlice, a)
}
```

Here you create at every iteration new variable with its own pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adrian stated This has nothing to do with memory. The `A` struct is actually contains a pointer to integer value.

```
type A struct {
    Number *int
}
```

So when you are assigning the value from `bSlice` to `A` struct and then appending the `A` struct in `aSlice` which is of `A` struct type. It will append the values as it is supposed to do inside Golang.

But you are changing the value at address pointed by `A` struct. And initialed with a new value in each iteration which changes the value at that address.

```
a.Number = &v.Number // here a.Number points to the same address
```

Hence the aSlice contains the value of last updated integer which is `3`. Since aSlice is a slice of A struct it contains the value inside A struct which is `3`.

But if you do not create a pointer to `int` inside `A` struct

```
type A struct {
    Number int
}
```

you will get the output as expected with different address now as.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Number int
}

type B struct {
    Number int
}

func main() {
    aSlice := []A{}
    bSlice := []B{B{1}, B{2}, B{3}}
    fmt.Println("----Assignment Loop----")
    for _, v := range bSlice {
        a := A{}
        a.Number = v.Number
        aSlice = append(aSlice, a)
        fmt.Printf("bSlice Value %v Pointer %v\n", v.Number, &v.Number)
        fmt.Printf("  a    Value %v Pointer %v\n", a.Number, &a.Number)
    }
    fmt.Println("\n----After Assignment----")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", aSlice)
    for i, _ := range aSlice {
        fmt.Println(aSlice[i].Number)
    }
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uNyFjHsjga7)

In Golang spec It is defined for composite Literals as :

> Taking the address of a composite literal generates a pointer to a
>   unique variable initialized with the literal's value.

```
type Point3D struct { x, y, z float64 }
var pointer *Point3D = &Point3D{y: 1000}
```